# How to guarantee an email is unique?

Tags: email, email-headers

An email has a Message-ID that is guarenteed unique by either the client program sending the email or the first email server ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID)).

To declare an email as unique then, I'd need both the Message-ID and an ID of the client program sending the email or first mail server- is this possible?  I can't find any reference to the latter in the following email standards:

- [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.2)
- [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you need these IDs? How is your problem related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase to guarentee incoming emails are unique, to avoid duplication of emails.  If this isn't the appropriate place to ask, please feel free to suggest another stack exchange platform that would be better

Comment: Shouldn't the sending mailserver provide that guarantee?

Comment: That's the issue though, the sending mail server can only guarentee that it's unique as per the sending mail server.  2 emails from separate mail servers could have the same Message-ID

Comment: Unless I'm fundementally misunderstanding that part, and it's unique across mail servers

Comment: Yes, that might be the case, but still I don't get how your problem is related to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail clients often use a [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for this purpose – which (in this case) is just a special formatting of a random number. Since 122 of the 128 bits are chosen randomly, the chance of a collision is vanishingly small.

There are two main reasons why mail clients should add the `Message-ID`:

- If the outgoing mail server adds the `Message-ID`, then this information is missing in the sent folder on the incoming mail server, which means the sender couldn't use it for conversation threading, defeating its purpose.
- The mail client may submit several versions of the same message to the outgoing mail server, such as mentioning each `Bcc` recipient in its own copy of the message, and all these versions should have the same `Message-ID`.